# How to know whether a process in windows is running or not in python

Tags: python, process, taskmanager

I am using python 2.7 and windows 7 64 bit. I want to know whether a process(python.exe) is running or not  in task manager/Processes. 
I had gone through http://www.videntity.com/2010/05/check-to-make-sure-a-process-is-running-and-restart-it-if-its-not-a-recipe-in-python/, but it is not for windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you linked uses os.popen()([official docs here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen))

In windows, you should use "tasklist" as arg for os.popen(), rather than "ps -Af"

e.g.

```
>>> import os
>>> tmp = os.popen("tasklist").read()  # it would return a str type
>>> "python.exe" in tmp
True
```

Comment: Is this will work on windows 7, vista, XP with 32 bit machine

Comment: well, it will work as long as tasklist works in cmd, so i guess yes

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it with `win32`:

```
from win32com.client import GetObject
WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')
processes = WMI.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')

if "python.exe" in [process.Properties_('Name').Value for process in processes]:
    #do the thing
```

Comment: Is this will work on windows 7, vista, XP with 32 bit machine

Comment: This will definitely work on any Windows 7 machine (32 or 64 bit).  It _should_ work on earlier versions, but to be honest, I'm not sure how far back compatibility goes

Comment: And what about windows 8 and vista

Comment: @imp Should be the same deal, I'd expect it to work, but I haven't done the research to be absolutely sure

Comment: Works on my tests in a Windows 7, 32 and 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see your process in the Background Processes in the processes tab of the task manager with the name pythonw.exe(64 bit)